# Illumina vs PacBio vs Nanopore price

Tags: ngs

Can someone help me with comparing the cost per run of Illumina, PacBio and Nanopore sequencing technologies?

Comment: Voted to keep open. I honestly think, although it's a wide question, it's essential for planning of any genomics project and it's not like these comparisons don't exist!

Comment: Could you please add more context to this, or narrow your question? Searching Google Scholar for [illumina nanopore pacbio](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=illumina%20pacbio%20nanopore) turns up *thousands* of comparative results papers, and StackExchange doesn't work well with thousands of answers.

Comment: You don't think that the kind of experiment you want to run is at all relevant?

Comment: voted to keep open, agree with Kamil S Jaron. This is information that is often intentionally obscured to the consumer by sequencing providers, but is essential for anyone trying to plan. compiling information is important for the community.